# Find integral of part of a set between two planes

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a measurable and bounded set in a half-space $\{z>0\}$. 
Let $ m = \lambda_3(A)$
and $(a,b,c)$ be center of mass of $A$.

Let $0<\alpha<\beta$, for $t>0$ let $f(t)$ be the measure of a part of set $A$ between planes $z=\alpha t$ and $z=\beta t$.

> Find $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$, using letters given above.

Please, may anyone help me? I have no idea even how to begin. I'm confused and I don't know how to use given information. I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$q(z):=\lambda_2\bigl(\{(x,y)\ |\ (x,y,z)\in A\}\bigr)$$
be the area obtained by intersecting $A$ with a horizontal plane at level $z$. Then by Fubini's theorem
$$f(t)=\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} q(z)\ dz\ ;$$ furthermore the $z$-component $c$ of the center of mass of $A$ can be expressed as
$$ c={1\over m}\int_0^\infty z q(z)\ dz\ .\tag{1}$$
Interchanging the order of integration in the double integral
$$Q:=\int_0^\infty f(t)\ dt=\int_0^\infty\left(\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}q(z) \ dz\right)\ dt$$
we obtain
$$Q=\int_0^\infty\left( q(z)\int_{z/\beta}^{z/\alpha}\ dt\right)\ dz=\int_0^\infty q(z)\left({z\over\alpha}-{z\over\beta}\right)\ dz\ .$$
Using $(1)$ we now conclude that
$$Q=m c\left({1\over\alpha}-{1\over\beta}\right)\ .$$